# How to take user input and create an object with it?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I have labels and inputs setup for the user to enter info, but how do I take that info, and create an object with it under a predefined model?

Lets say I have a book model. The user needs to enter the books title, and author. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you take a look to `ModelForm`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create forms for a specific model and save the corresponding object. From the [`ModelForm` Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/):

> If you’re building a database-driven app, chances are you’ll have forms that map closely to Django models. For instance, you might have a BlogComment model, and you want to create a form that lets people submit comments. In this case, it would be redundant to define the field types in your form, because you’ve already defined the fields in your model.

And a quick example

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # ...

# The form class.
class BookForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Book
         fields = ('title', 'author', )

# Use your form in a template and then in the view:
f = BookForm(request.POST)
if f.is_valid():
    new_book = f.save()
```